# C#: Check if any key was pressed in Console

Tags: c#

Both `Console.Read()` and `Console.ReadKey()` seem to wait for a key to be pressed. How can I detect if anything was pressed without actually asking for the program to wait till a key is pressed?

Comment: No; he wants to find out whether a key was pressed in his program's console, not in the rest of the system.

Comment: That's right. So far the need has not arisen for me to create a keylogger. Instead this question was to facilitate more of a debugging nuisance. It was one of those things which you know if you know the language well - but which (I personally) find difficult to search from the documentation.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can poll on [Console.KeyAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable.aspx) to know if you can read anything.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into using Event Handlers. For using Windows forms the following should be helpful. [Control.Keypress Event (System.Windows.Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(VS.71).aspx). For a good overview of Event Handlers in general, take a look at [EventHandling in .NET using C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ddutta/EventHandlingInNetUsingCS11092005052726AM/EventHandlingInNetUsingCS.aspx).

For a console application, you should look into the `Console.CancelKeyPress Event` function.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following where you want to wait:

```
while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {}
```