# Detect if a key is down without waiting for key press in C# console application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, keydown, keyevent

**How can I check whether a specific key is down, and do nothing if another or no key is pressed?**

I want something like this pseudocode in a Visual C# console application:

```
while (true) {
    if (IsKeyDown(Escape)) { //checks if Escape is down
        println("Press enter to resume");
        waitKey(Enter); //waits until Enter is pressed
    }
    //do something
}
```

This loop will keep doing something, until the Escape key is pressed. If the Escape key is pressed, the loop will pause until the Enter key is pressed.

#### I've tried:

- `Console.ReadKey()` - will just pause the loop until any key is pressed.
- `Keyboard.IsKeyDown()` - has no effect in a console application.

Comment: `println` is Java.  Are you sure you have the right tags?  :P

Comment: quick google search gave me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770518/c-check-if-any-key-was-pressed-in-console

Comment: You need an event, [KeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example

Comment: Other answers for listening for Console.KeyAvailable are good, but this may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988197/capture-keystroke-without-focus-in-console

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
using System;

class Example 
{
  public static void Main() 
  {
    ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
    // Prevent example from ending if CTL+C is pressed.
    Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Press any combination of CTL, ALT, and SHIFT, and a console key.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press the Escape (Esc) key to quit: \n");
    do 
    {
       cki = Console.ReadKey();
       Console.Write(" --- You pressed ");
       if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Alt) != 0) Console.Write("ALT+");
       if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Shift) != 0) Console.Write("SHIFT+");
       if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0) Console.Write("CTL+");
       Console.WriteLine(cki.Key.ToString());
     } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
  }
 }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have the exact answer...

while(true)
{
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss "));

    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to resume");
            } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(100);}

Comment: I realise this question is closed, but would it not be helpful to have the exact code sample answer provided for this question as per the psuedocode in the question?