# Detecting SINGLE key presses in CONSOLE C#

Tags: c#, keypress

I'm new to coding and have decided to start with C#. I've decided to write a simple console program that will detect key press and if only Enter is pressed, it will show number. The problem is that you can just hold down key and it will continue to show numbers. What should I add to my code so program will detect only *SINGLE* presses and ignore if user is *HOLDING* the key?
(I didn't find anything about this issue for *CONSOLE* `C#`, only for Forms one. Neither on this forum, nor in Web at all)

Thanks in advance

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to play!");

    int num = 0;
    void WaitForKey(ConsoleKey key)
    {
        while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != key)
        { }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        WaitForKey(ConsoleKey.Enter);
        Console.Write("{0} ", num);
        num++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not declare a method (WaitForKey) inside another method(Main)

Comment: @L.B Actually, C# 7.0 introduces local functions https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/

Comment: @L.B well, it works (doesn't show any mistakes) and it works for me)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: Check if any key was pressed in Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770518/c-check-if-any-key-was-pressed-in-console)

Comment: It is not a problem, it is a *feature*.  Your program is already running millions of times slower than it could run, incrementing a number takes a fraction of a nanosecond.  But to the human eye, the keyboard repeat is quick enough to look instant.  Even though it takes a good 100 milliseconds, an eon in processor cycles.  You will have to re-think this, we can't tell what you intended to accomplish from the snippet.  Don't use Thread.Sleep() to make it even slower.

Comment: @HansPassant that isn't the snippet, that's the whole programm. I've clearly described what I intended to do: I want programm to detect only single keypresses and ignore if user is HOLDING key down.

Comment: If that's the entire program then you don't have a problem, any user will very quickly tire of it and delete it again.  Hiding the true intention is never a good idea, nobody can propose a useful alternative.  As-is, you have to be able to get the equivalent of a KeyUp event, you can't get that from the Console.  It was meant to keep user interaction in a program very simple, that was quite intentional as well.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: @HansPassant I know that it is not very interesting for users, it shouldn't entertain because I made it for personal purpose and I don't in any way hide my true intention. As I understood from your comment, it is impossible to do what I wanted to in Console, only in Forms?

Answer (score 1):

If your task is to count amount of changes of typed/holded keys you can do it with just remembering of last key

```
var lastChar = char.MaxValue;
var index = 0;
do
{
    var x = Console.ReadKey();
    if (lastChar != x.KeyChar)
    {
        lastChar = x.KeyChar;
        Console.WriteLine(++index);
    }
} while (index < 10);
```

If you need to define single key you can use `StopWatch` class to check time lapsed from previous key had come (in the example 300 is only for testing, I would suggest to research it deeply if that is fit your goal)

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
do
{
    var x = Console.ReadKey();
    if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 300)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(++index);
    }
    sw.Restart();
} while (index < 10);
```

or combine both of the ways

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you cant use `ReadKey` here. I would recommend to use [ReadConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) WinApi function. You can write wrapper class for this purpose, for example:

```
internal class KeyboardInput
{
    private readonly short _exitKey;
    private readonly uint[] _keyStates = new uint[short.MaxValue]; 

    public KeyboardInput(ConsoleKey exitKey)
    {
        _exitKey = (short) exitKey;

        // subscribe with empty delegates to prevent null reference check before call
        OnKeyDown += delegate { };
        OnKeyUp += delegate { };
    }

    public event Action<char, short> OnKeyDown;
    public event Action<char, short> OnKeyUp;

    public void Run()
    {
        var exitKeyPressed = false;
        var nRead = 0;
        var records = new INPUT_RECORD[10];

        var handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
        while (!exitKeyPressed)
        {
            ReadConsoleInputW(handle, records, records.Length, ref nRead);

            for (var i = 0; i < nRead; i++)
            {
                // process only Key events
                if (records[i].EventType != KEY_EVENT) continue;

                // process key state
                ProcessKey(records[i].KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode, records[i].KeyEvent.bKeyDown,
                    records[i].KeyEvent.UnicodeChar);

                // check for exit key press
                if ((exitKeyPressed = records[i].KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode == _exitKey) == true) break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessKey(short virtualKeyCode, uint keyState, char key)
    {
        if (_keyStates[virtualKeyCode] != keyState)
            if (keyState == 1) OnKeyDown(key, virtualKeyCode);
            else OnKeyUp(key, virtualKeyCode);

        _keyStates[virtualKeyCode] = keyState;
    }

    #region Native methods

    private const short KEY_EVENT = 0x0001;
    private const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool ReadConsoleInputW(IntPtr hConsoleInput, [Out] INPUT_RECORD[] lpBuffer, int nLength,
        ref int lpNumberOfEventsRead);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct INPUT_RECORD
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public readonly short EventType;

        //union {
        [FieldOffset(4)] public KEY_EVENT_RECORD KeyEvent;

        //[FieldOffset(4)]
        //public MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD MouseEvent;
        //[FieldOffset(4)]
        //public WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD WindowBufferSizeEvent;
        //[FieldOffset(4)]
        //public MENU_EVENT_RECORD MenuEvent;
        //[FieldOffset(4)]
        //public FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD FocusEvent;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct KEY_EVENT_RECORD
    {
        public readonly uint bKeyDown;
        public readonly short wRepeatCount;
        public readonly short wVirtualKeyCode;
        public readonly short wVirtualScanCode;
        public readonly char UnicodeChar;
        public readonly int dwControlKeyState;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Example of usage:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kbInput = new KeyboardInput(ConsoleKey.Escape);
        kbInput.OnKeyDown += OnKeyDown;
        kbInput.OnKeyUp += OnKeyUp;

        kbInput.Run();
    }

    private static void OnKeyDown(char key, short code)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key pressed: {key} (virtual code: 0x{code:X})");
    }

    private static void OnKeyUp(char key, short code)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key released: {key} (virtual code: 0x{code:X})");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add a method keyRelease like that in your loop for after num++ :
 WaitForKeyRelease(ConsoleKey.Enter);

And in your method : while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == key)

You wait until the key pressed is not enter so it's like a key release.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if "enter" is inputted by doing something like this:

`

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input == "") {
     //do stuff
}
```

`