# C#, console, how to check if key is pressed, and change variables in real time accordingly

Tags: c#

Edited 2017 07 30 13:49
The main difference between this and the other question is that: 
How to detect 2 pressed key at the same time?

For example: a program that display "2" on the screen only if key A and B are pressed at the same time. When either A or B or both are released, it display "1"

The following program does not work, because ReadKey need to wait.

if (Console.KeyAvailable){} Also doesn't work, because it only allow one key to be read, not if multiple is pressed at the same time.

In short, I wish someone can tell me a function that, when used, immediately out put a Boolean value depend on if a certain key is pressed without letting the program to wait

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number = 2;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();

                if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.B & Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.A)
                {
                    Console.Write(2);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to C# right now I wish to know if there is a way to check if key is pressed, and change variables in real time accordingly.

I have a program that out put an number after a key is pressed, however, its update rate is too slow and it can only check for one key at a time. (It can only recognize A or B if I am pressing AB at the same time.)

Is there a function that out put an Boolean value and does not block the code like Console.ReadKey()? (or something similar) For example "function(A)" will out put a "true" if A is pressed at the time this function is used. If not, it out put a "false" and program proceed to the next line.

In short can you tell me how to program a console, so that it will have a list of variables that reflect keys pressed in real time?

(Using while(true) loop, at anytime I am pressing the key A. Program write variable KeyA=true, at any time it is not pressed, KeyA=false)

Tried event, but can not get it to work. ("Does not exist" error during compilation)

This is the program I am using.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number = 2;
            while (true)
            {
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    var key = Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Write((int)key.KeyChar);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar questions in 2 minutes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393158/detecting-single-key-presses-in-console-c-sharp

Comment: You can't use ReadKey for this, or any of the console methods. You must check for key down state in other ways, most likely using P/Invoke if you're not using a winform or wpf system where most of this is handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

See this code:

```
class Program
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (GetAsyncKeyState('Q') == 0)
        {
            short result = GetAsyncKeyState('A');
            if (result < 0 && (result & 0x01) == 0x01)
                Console.WriteLine("A pressed and up");
        }
    }
}
```

Press Q to quit or A to see a message that is was pressed. You can also use the GetKeyboardState API to retrieve information on all keys at once. Be sure to read the documentation to have a proper understanding of return values and usage.

Comment: Thank you so much! This function is exactly what I need.